# How to switch Spring profiles on runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Currently I inject to my application properties via @Value and it works just fine. Now I want my application to support more than one configuration, which means its @Value should return different value each time.

I read about spring profiles, but I couldn't understand how can I switch profile on runtime. Is it even possible?

What I really need is to load all of the configuration when the server starts and choose its profile dynamically when a request arrives - each request should have one set of configurations.

Comment: Actually you can switch profiles passing JVM params during starting spring up. If it is spring boot you know that you can create profile based properties like `application.properties`, `application-{profile}.properties`. For example: `application-dev.properties` and you need pass `spring.profiles.active=dev` during starting service up on dev it will automatically load `application.properties` and override params which exists in `application-dev.properties` file

Comment: If this not what you are looking for could you please provide more info?

Comment: I think what OP want is to switch the profile **after** the application has started, since OP wants to switch the profile dynamically when a request arrives (which can only happened after the application has started). Therefore, your suggestion won't work.

Comment: Profiles are not meant to be used like that, It's most often used when projects starts to select a Bean instead of another based on the current selected profile. Or to load parameters from a specific application-xxxx.propeties. But hot-profile switching is not something that can be done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Switching Spring profiles during runtime is not a good practice. Spring profile is meant to be used as a way to manage your application across different **environments**.

> Spring Profiles provide a way to segregate parts of your application configuration and make it be available only in certain environments

If you have a variable that needs to change dynamically for every incoming requests, consider these several options:

- Store the value in DB, cache on start, and fetch based on the incoming request parameters/body
- Infer the value from incoming request parameters/body
- Store all the possible values in properties file, load on start, and select based on incoming request parameters/body
- Store all the possible values as enum/constants and select bsaed on incoming request parameters/body

Comment: What if I want to pass the profile by command-line argument using a name different from -Dspring.profiles.active?